# how to access data outside of the function JavaScript (reading a file)

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, variables, scope

```
var lines = [];
document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", readSingleFile, true);

console.log(lines.length);


function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var read = new FileReader();
        read.onload = function(evt) {
            var contents = evt.target.result;
            var ct = read.result;
            var lines = ct.split('\n');
        }
        read.readAsText(f);
    }
}


...
<body>
     <input type="file" id = "fileInput">
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

I want to read the content of the file to array lines. The console.log(lines.length) returns 0(which I think is because variables in js have function scope). How can I access the values in array 'lines' outside of the function. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `console.log()` instruction runs immediately (before the `change` event of the `fileInput` or the `load` event of the `FileReader`). Move the `console.log()` into the `load` callback so that it runs when the file has been successfully loaded and `lines` is populated.

You do need to remove the `var` on the `lines` variable declaration inside your function though so that the original variable doesn't get shadowed.

```
var lines = [];
document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", readSingleFile, true);

function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var read = new FileReader();
        read.onload = function(evt) {
            var contents = evt.target.result;
            var ct = read.result;
            lines = ct.split('\n');

            console.log(lines.length);
        }
        read.readAsText(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to access the array outside of the function?

Comment: @Majmun By removing the second `var`, you won't have a second `lines` variable and, as long as you access `lines` after the events that populate it, you can access it from outside the function.

Comment: @Quentin Answer updated.

Comment: @Majmun — Time travel is not possible. You can't read a value before it is assigned.

Comment: @Quentin but is it possible to put the 'console.log(lines.length)' anywhere outside of the function (doesn't matter where) and it will give me the number of the lines read?

Comment: @Majmun – You could put it in a different function, which you don't call unless *after* you have assigned the value. But that would be silly. Pass arguments. Don't use globals.

Comment: @Majmun As the whole point of my answer shows, you have to wait until `lines` is populated before you can access it, so no, you can't have `console.log()` anywhere outside the function. You can access `lines` from outside the function, but only after it's been populated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom event, and add a listener to it...

```js
let lines = [];
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", readSingleFile, true)
fileInput.addEventListener('lines:filled', handleLines);

const event = new Event('lines:filled');

function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var read = new FileReader();
        read.onload = function(evt) {
            var contents = evt.target.result;
            var ct = read.result;
            lines = ct.split('\n');
            
            fileInput.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        read.readAsText(f);
    }
}

function handleLines() {
  console.log(lines);
}
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file"/>
```